# How to find all objects with an attribute that matches any of the values in another collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, select, enums

I have a collection with objects in it, one of these objects attribute is a PublishRequestStatus, which is an enum value.

I'm recieving another list of all enum values that it needs to match, now I know how to search for 1 attribute matching a value:

```
model = model.Where(x => x.PublishRequestStatus == PublishRequestStatus.Denied);
```

But I'm having trouble matching all possible values from another collection. For example if I have a collection with `PublishRequestStatus.Approved` and `PublishRequestStatus.Denied`, how would I use LINQ to search for all objects with either of those enum values?

The only thing that I found what works is to make one list for each enum value in the 2nd collection in a loop, and at the end join all the lists together. However, I'm pretty sure that LINQ has a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
model = model.Where(x => myEnumList.Contains(x.PublishRequestStatus));
```

Alternativly with `.Any()`:

```
model = model.Where(x => myEnumList.Any(y => y == x.PublishRequestStatus));
```

EDIT: According to Yuvals answer you may also simply check if your current element `x` has any of the flags:

```
model = model.Where(x => x.PublishRequestStatus.HasFlags(otherFlags));
```

This assumes your enum looks similar to this:

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum { ... }
```

Which will allow bitwise `|`.

Comment: Those both seem to work. Is there any difference? (Speed, etc).  It shouldn't really matter to much since the enum won't contain much more than ~6 values, so just out of interest.

Comment: Okay, I'll accept this as an answer when it lets me. Thank you!

Comment: read this as when to use the one over the other: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526773/what-is-the-difference-between-contains-and-any-in-linq

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445219/linq-ring-any-vs-contains-for-huge-collections

Answer (score 3):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but more of a suggestion. Instead of receiving a `List<SomeEnum>`, you can simply use bitwise `|` on your enum values, and look them up using `Enum.HasFlags`:

```
var flags = PublishRequestStatus.Approved | PublishRequestStatus.Denied;
var otherFlags = PublishRequestStatus.Approved | 
                 PublishRequestStatus.Denied | 
                 PublishRequestStatus.MaybeApproved;

Console.WriteLine(otherFlags.HasFlags(flags)); // Yields true.
```

Assuming such a thing is possible.

Comment: I had a look at using bitflags cause of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194333/mvc-2-passing-enum-to-checkboxfor, however I'd have to change a lot of an existing system. I'll see if it's worth the change and it'll work in my context.

Comment: @anthonytimmers Good luck :). It would definitely save you unnecessary iterations.

Answer (score 1):

The best from performance point of view is to avoid lambdas that introduce closure. So if you have

```
ICollection<PublishRequestStatus> filter = ...;
```

where `filter` could be `List<PublishRequestStatus>`, `PublishRequestStatus[]` or better `HashSet<PublishRequestStatus>`.

Then you can use `method group` predicate:

```
model = model.Where(filter.Contains);
```

Comment: The filter is a PublishRequestStatus[]. I don't know what you mean with introduces closure, but I'll have to read up in my free time on what exactly closure means in terms of coding. Model is of type GamePublishRequestViewModel[]. The status in this model is located at Model.PublishRequest.PublishRequestStatus, so I think lambda is necessary (?) and `model.Where(filter.Contains)` won't work.

Comment: Every `T[]` is also implementing a lot of interfaces, including `ICollection<T>`. So if you have a variable `filter` of type `PublishRequestStatus>[]`, try the following `ICollection<PublishRequestStatus> c = filter;` and will see that it will compile w/o errors. To apply it to my answer, just use `model.Where(((ICollection<PublishRequestStatus>)filter).Contains)`.

Comment: What about closures, it's good to know and there are a lot of sources, including SO with good explanation, but shortly it is a compiler generated class that is instantiated and holds some of your local variables as fields to make lambda that needs them working. See this for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425833/why-does-c-sharp-compiler-create-private-displayclass-when-using-linq-method-any