# Getting all types under a userdefined assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, system.reflection

I am trying to get all the types defined under a particular userdefined namespace

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.Namespace == "namespace")


    <>c__DisplayClass3_0    
    <>c__DisplayClass4_0    
    <>c__DisplayClass6_0    
    <>c__DisplayClass2_0    
    <>c__DisplayClass2_1    
    <>c__DisplayClass2_2    
    <>c__DisplayClass2_3    
    <>c__DisplayClass2_4    
    <>c__DisplayClass2_5    
    <>c__DisplayClass2_6    
    <>c__DisplayClass2_7    
    <>c__DisplayClass2_8
```

My question 
Why am i getting these extra type which are not defined under that namespace?

how do i select type that are user defined types?

some one explain me what are these and how they get defined under a userdefined namespace.

Comment: these are classes generated by the compiler

Comment: how do i select type that are user defined types?

Comment: These are generated by compiler for closures. Read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425833/why-does-c-sharp-compiler-create-private-displayclass-when-using-linq-method-any

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are all types generated by the compiler. The C# compiler generates types to implement things like:

- Lambda expressions and anonymous methods
- Iterator blocks
- Async methods
- Anonymous types

All of them should have the [`CompilerGeneratedAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) applied to them, so you can filter them out that way if you want:

```
var types = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.Namespace == "namespace")
    .Where(t => !t.GetTypeInfo().IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true));
```

Comment: how do i filter only user defined type from this ?

Comment: @sriram: As I say, filter out ones that have `CompilerGeneratedAttribute`  applied. I'm writing up an example.

Comment: thanks a lot, but the type.isDefined is not there in .net core.

Comment: @sriram: You need to use `GetTypeInfo()` in .NET Core to get the associated `TypeInfo`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot man. it's an honor to get an answer from the great JonSkeet :)

Answer (score 4):

These are generated by compiler for closures.

This question explains **why** they are created: [Why does C# compiler create private DisplayClass when using LINQ method Any() and how can I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425833/why-does-c-sharp-compiler-create-private-displayclass-when-using-linq-method-any)

You can check for `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` to know which classes are compiler-generated and remove them from your collection:

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetTypes()
   .Where(t => t.Namespace == "namespace")
   .Where(x => !x.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttributes<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>().Any());
```