# Filter GetTypes() to remove extra type created from partial class with async method

Tags: c#, reflection

If I have a partial class like this:

```cs
    public partial class ExampleClass { }
    public partial class ExampleClass
    {
        public async Task ValidateAsync() =>
            await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
```

and I run `GetTypes()` on its assembly:

```cs
    Type asmType = typeof(ExampleClass);
    Assembly asm = asmType.Assembly;
    List<Type> m1 = asm.GetTypes();
```

I get two types for `ExampleClass`, one normal one and an extra one with name suffix related to `ValidateAsync`.

This extra type is a pain because in Release builds it is optimised to a struct (class in Debug builds) and I want to filter it out.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068213/getting-all-types-under-a-userdefined-assembly

Comment: Thanks you @EfraimNewman, that solved my problem.